# Connection to a service via facebook : connected on mobile app to get connected on a service on server

Tags: php, ios, facebook, laravel, facebook-php-sdk

A user uses my mobile app, he would like to connect to my service FOO with facebook connect.

He presses the button "connection with facebook" in the app, then connects to facebook (code written with the facebook sdk).

Once he/she is connected, the app needs to check if the person is an actual user of my service FOO by doing a call to the service's back-end.

The facebook id of the user is passed in a POST call.

If the user has an id in the database, then it gets the service's token from the server, and is then identified.

If not, the user is created.

The question is the following : how could the service's back-end be sure that it is the relevant facebook account, and not a fake call to a server with these details ? How, with the data from facebook, could the user be properly identified to the server's service ?

Comment: You could use the access token from the iOS sdk and make sure it is valid for the facebook id in question

Comment: Send the token only, not a user id or other data. Use that token on the server-side to make a `/me` API request to get the user details.